# LDA and chosing topic

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, lda

I have recently digged into LDA, it seems pretty reasonable but i am left with few questions which i am unable to find answers for.

For Lda, we first represent korpus as vector where

```
           word1 , word2 , word3 , wordN
document1   n       n        n       n
document2   n       n        n       n
documentN   n       n        n       n
```

This tells us, how many times word j from vocabullary appears in document i.

1st question)

Do we create vocabullary V randomly from words from all documents or do we chose it such that every word in V is present in every document atleast once?

next we create matrix for every document

```
        topic1  topic2 topicN
 word1   n         n     n
 word2   n         n     n
 word3   n         n     n
 word4   n         n     n
```

We select topics we want to represent in our documents, and randomly assign word to document ( wordi x topij = 1 if word belongs to topic, 0 otherwise )

next for every word we calculate their new topic using formula

P = P1 * P2

Where

```
P1 = Probability( topic T | document d )
P2 = Probability( word W | topic T )
```

Now new topic K is assigned to the word W with probability P.

2nd question)

What topic do we chose as T and to what topic do we assigne probability P for word W?
I failed to find the answer for this.

Thanks for answer